# Cannot Boot - Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 9.10 from my laptop onto a HDD in an external harddrive enclosure.

I could not connect online so I plugged it into another computer and updated the system.

Now when I plugged it back into my laptop, I cannot boot.

It says "ALERT! /dev/sdd1 does not exist. Dropping to shell!" and has a shell that says `(initramfs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grub2 is pointing at a device which does not exist...this is odd but can happen for some reasons. Please follow [this guide to recover Grub2 via a Live-CD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover%20Grub%202%20via%20LiveCD), if you have any further problems, please edit your question and add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your boot manager is referring to a boot device that doesn't exist.

If you install an OS to a USB drive (disk, stick, etc.) remember that the device node that is used to access your disk may change from time to time. That's because these nodes are generated dynamically. Try to boot on the other machine again and edit your boot manager's config (`/boot/grub/menu.lst` ?)

Use the devices uuids (see: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`) instead of their device nodes. Edit your fstab, too!

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 uses GRUB2 which does not have a `menu.lst`!

Comment: That's why i added the question mark.